# Making checkbox fainter and larger

Tags: symbols, amssymb, questionnaire

I would like to make a checkbox fainter so that the manual input could be better perceived and larger. How can I make it ?

```
   \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage[small,sf,bf]{titlesec}
 \setromanfont{Georgia}
\usepackage{setspace, amssymb} 
\doublespacing
\newcommand{\checkbox}{$\square$}
\begin{document} 
If appropriate \checkbox  . Why appropriate, specify? ...........
If inappropriate \checkbox . Why inappropriate, specify? ..............
If appropriate \checkbox . Why appropriate, specify? ...........\\
If inappropriate \checkbox . Why inappropriate, specify? ...........
 \end{document
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `\checkmark` rather than `\checkbox`? Alternatively, did you have `\CheckedBox` of the `wasysym` package in mind?

Comment: There is no way to get a fainter `\checkbox`. It is an undefined command; thus, TeX's error recovery ignores the command and does not typeset it at all.

Comment: `\usepackage{xcolor}\newcommand*\checkbox{{\Huge\color{gray!25}$\square$}}` ?

Comment: Don't end lines with `\\ ` outside `tabular`, `array` etc. environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you load the `xcolor` package and define medium-gray and light-gray versions of `$\square$`.

I've simplified your code so that it'll run under pdfLaTeX as well as under XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. I've chosen `\Large`, but you're obviously free to choose `\large`, `\huge`, `\Huge`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, xcolor} 

\newcommand{\checkbox}{$\square$}
\newcommand{\lightcheckbox}{{\Large\textcolor{gray}{\checkbox}}}
\newcommand{\verylightcheckbox}{{\Large\textcolor{lightgray}{\checkbox}}}

\begin{document} 
\checkbox \lightcheckbox \verylightcheckbox \checkbox
\end{document}
```